# Clear interval auto refresh

Tags: jquery, clearinterval

I want to clear the var autorefresh by mousedown event but it didn't work.

Load on document ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#posts_db').load('data/posts_db.php');
});
```

Start Interval 60 seconds

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function(){
$('#posts_db<?php echo $id ?>').load('data/posts_db.php');
}, 60000);
```

mousedown touchstart to change interval to 1800 seconds (for the commentarea)

```
// Comment_on Button wechselt von 60 sek auf 30 Min
$('#comment_on<?php echo $id ?>').bind('mousedown touchstart', function () {
$("#comment_on<?php echo $id ?>").stop().fadeOut("fast");
$("#comment_off<?php echo $id ?>").stop().delay(200).fadeIn("fast");
$("#element<?php echo $id ?>").stop().slideDown("slow");
clearInterval(auto_refresh);

// Intervall db load nach 1800 Sekunden während Eingabe
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function()
{
$('#posts_db').load('data/posts_db.php');
}, 1800000);
});
```

mousedown touchstart to change interval back to 60 seconds (if the user decides not to write any comment)

```
// Wenn Kommentar Fenster geschlossen wird Intervall wieder auf 60 Sekunden

$('#comment_off<?php echo $id ?>').bind('mousedown touchstart', function () {

$("#comment_off<?php echo $id ?>").stop().fadeOut("fast");
$("#comment_on<?php echo $id ?>").stop().delay(200).fadeIn("fast");
$("#element<?php echo $id ?>").stop().slideUp("slow");
clearInterval(auto_refresh);


// Intervall db load nach 60 Sekunden
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function()
{

$('#posts_db').load('data/posts_db.php');
}, 60000);

});
```

it works to change the auto_refresh into 1800 seconds but to go back to 60 seconds didn't work.

Comment: Initialise `var auto_refresh` globally or outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you keep creating auto_refresh in local scopes. declare auto_refresh globally and then instead of creating local versions, just set the global value:

```
clearInterval(auto_refresh);

auto_refresh = setInterval(
function()
{
  $('#posts_db').load('data/posts_db.php');
}, 1800000);
```

Comment: Ok somehow it didnt work.. I changed it but now the mousedown event didnt change the interval